# How to use a Dictionary without declaring it in advance?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I can easily use a string array without declaring it in advance using something like this:

```
new string[]{"MyString1","MyString2"}
```

And use it as a method parameter without having to declare a variable for it in advance. However I can't do this properly with `Dictionary<string,string>`. 
I tried:

```
new Dictionary<string,string>(){"1","2"}
```

And

```
new Dictionary<string,string>().Add("1","2"):
```

None of above worked in terms of being compiled.

Comment: Describe "not worked". And provide the surrounding code. This is vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: i tried to edit it a bit more to make it clearer.I hope its enough now?If it is not please reply back to me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do it this way

```
new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"Key1","Value1"},{"Key2","Value2"}};
```

Every Dictionary entry is a combination of a Key and a corresponding value. Hence first entry is `{"Key1","Value1"}` where Key is `"Key1"` and value is `"Value1"` and so and so forth.

> And use it as a method parameter without having to declare a variable for it in advance. However I can't do this properly with Dictionary. I tried :
>
> ```
> new Dictionary<string,string>().Add("1","2"):
> ```

This cannot be used for method parameter as `Add` method does not return anything. Its a void method.

**Food for thought:** Your `new string[]{"MyString1","MyString2"}`  is single dimensional array namely `string[]` whereas dictionary is like string[x][2] where x is length of dictionary. (string[x][2] is just for representation purpose. I know its illegal declaration)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "1", "2" }, { "3", "4" }
};
```

You need additional brackets to initialize the Key-Value pairs of which the dictionary consists. Those brackets basically call `Add()`, and since `Add()` takes two parameters (key and value), you put two items inside those brackets.

This approach can be used for any Collection where the `Add()` method takes multiple parameters.

See here for more info about object and collection initializers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Or, about initializing a dictionary:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208